# How can i add cooling fan in series or parallel with a led diode

Tags: led, fan

I am new to this hobby and forum and would like to thank anyone for there help,
I have found it quite easy to connect leds in series or parralel but now i need to add a fan to a small system to keep it small.

I am using one LED diode rated at 9-12v dc 800ma

I have been using Constant current drivers for this.

My question is how can I add a 12v dc 0.09ma cooling to this simple circuit, I am aware I will need to add a resitor and am also willing to use a different rate power supply.

Please offer your suggeestions as I have searched the internet to no avail.

Thankyou

Comment: What is your power supply? Voltage and current rating?

Comment: If your LED is driven at 800mA and your fan draws 90mA (I suppose you meant 0.09A / 90mA instead of 0.09mA / 90uA), then you can't use them in series.

Comment: the driver puts out 12v dc at 900 ma, (I am happy getting a new one if required)

Comment: a light emitting diode diode?

Answer (score 1):

The fan will want a constant voltage supply of 12V.  While it's possible you could just stick the fan in parallel with the LED and it would work okay, you would be stealing a bit of current from the LED and if the LED ever became open circuit, even for a moment, your fan would likely be destroyed because the open-circuit voltage of the CC driver would be much higher than the normal operating voltage.

So your best solution is a separate constant voltage 12V supply that can supply the required current. Most likely it will be capable of a lot more than 90mA, but that's not a problem provided you are within the minimum current spec of the supply (usually 0mA to 10% of the maximum current).

---

Edit: Possible protection to use one supply:

This will protect the fan up to about 55V with R2 a 5W resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRqjwx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the led will run between 9-12vdc so this should be acceptable

Comment: can i add a resister to protect the fan or led?

Comment: @aetdinger No, you cannot practically limit the voltage below 12 V with just resistors. However, it is possible that the LED driver has a voltage limit low enough to not damage fan if the LEDs become disconnected. If you have a multimeter you can power up the LED driver without anything attached, and measure the output voltage. If the output is at or below ~13 V without LEDs you can connect the fan in parallel with the LEDs .

Comment: all good suggestions, if I added a led that only requires 6v 800ma would I need a 22ohm resitor?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply connect fan to 12V, you can add L7812CV before constant current drivers and supply fan with it. Don't worry about burning down, fans are mostly tough things.